# Backup-manager The upload transfer "scp" failed

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, резервное-копирование

Здравствуйте, первое что попалось для бэкапа **Backup-manager**. Система Debian 6. Вроде c Backup-manager все гуд, но проблема... не могу закачивать бэкап на удаленный сервер. Нужно генерить ключи. Ок, сделано. Из консоли руками sftp, scp работают без запроса пароля. А вот Backup-manager выдает ошибку:

```
Unable to create login.backup.net:/
The upload transfer "scp" failed.
```

Кусог конфига:

```
export BM_UPLOAD_METHOD="scp"

# where to upload (global to all methods. Not required to be set for S3)
export BM_UPLOAD_HOSTS="login.backup.net"

# Where to put archives on the remote hosts (global)
export BM_UPLOAD_DESTINATION="/"

##############################################################
# The SSH method
#############################################################

# the user to use for the SSH connections/transfers
export BM_UPLOAD_SSH_USER="login"

# The private key to use for opening the connection
export BM_UPLOAD_SSH_KEY="/root/.ssh/id_rsa"

# specific ssh hosts 
export BM_UPLOAD_SSH_HOSTS=""

# port to use for SSH connections (leave blank for default one)
export BM_UPLOAD_SSH_PORT=""

# destination for ssh uploads (overrides BM_UPLOAD_DESTINATION)
export BM_UPLOAD_SSH_DESTINATION=""

# purge archives on remote hosts before uploading?
export BM_UPLOAD_SSH_PURGE="true"

# If you set BM_UPLOAD_SSH_PURGE, you can specify a time to live 
# for archives uploaded with SSH.
# This can let you use different ttl's locally and remotely
# By default, BM_ARCHIVE_TTL will be used.
export BM_UPLOAD_SSH_TTL=""
```

Уже мозг плавится. Из-за чего может быть ошибка?

Comment: Я не знаком с Backup-manager, но в качестве уточнения - архивы точно нужно записывать в корень удалённого узла и указанный пользователь - точно имеет право записи в корень?

Comment: @МАН69К через scp в любую папку записывается все что угодно, поэтому права в норме.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется что проблема в Backup-manager, так как Duplicity работает.